# Upload subfolders to amazon s3 using apache camel

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-camel

I am using `Apache camel` to upload files to `Amazon s3`. Does camel provides any provision to upload folders.

Actually I have an requirement which as follows, The polling should happen on daily basis to specific folder. Consider the folder structure `/photos/user` and inside that there are some sub folders like day1,day2.,

from (`file:\photos\user`) to (`aws-s3:bucket-name?access Key=<>&secret Key=<>`)

So the above code should pull the records from day1 folder and next day folders consequently as day progresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the recursive option like

> file:\photo\user?recursive=true

to consume files from the folders recursively.